Is it safe to echo back the Origin header in CORS responses without re-checking the whitelist in AWS Lambda?
We're developing an API using AWS Lambda functions. We have a single Lambda that handles all OPTIONS requests for CORS preflight checks. This Lambda verifies the Origin against a whitelist and, if valid, responds with:
{
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'https://exampledomain.com',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true'
}

For the actual API request (e.g., a POST or GET), we also want to include the same headers in the response to allow the browser to process the request correctly. However, we're wondering if it's safe to simply echo back the Origin value from the incoming request in the actual response instead of performing another whitelist validation.
For example:
OPTIONS request:
The Origin is checked against a whitelist.
If valid, the Lambda responds with a 200 status and the CORS headers.
Actual request (e.g., POST):
Instead of re-checking the Origin, we echo the Origin value in the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, like so:
{
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': request.headers.origin,
  'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true'
}

My questions are:
Is this approach secure, assuming the whitelist validation happens during the OPTIONS request?
Are there any potential pitfalls or best practices we should consider here?
Thanks for any advice!

I think this is reasonably safe, in cases where there actually is a preflight request happening. No browser that has not been manipulated, would have any reason to send a different Origin with the actual request, than it did with the OPTIONS request. "Manipulated" clients (or clients that don't adhere to CORS restrictions to begin with) can do anything they want, so they could send you an "allowed" Origin to begin with, no matter where the request is originating from. But are you sure every single possible cross-origin request will require a preflight request to begin with ...?

I believe you should validate the origin in the actual request too. HTTP requests are stateless, obviously, and OPTIONS preflight request is not linked to the actual request anyhow. Which opens a possibility for man-in-the-middle attack.
Theoretically, anyone could send correct headers to your actual HTTP handler (GET, POST, etc...) with malicious intent.
Given the statements above, I would rather handle options and an actual request in a lambda to make sure you are checking against a whitelisted origin every single time:
exports.handler = async (event) => {
  const whitelist = ['https://exampledomain.com', 'https://anotherdomain.com'];
  const origin = event.headers.origin || event.headers.Origin;
  const responseHeaders = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  };

  // Validate Origin
  if (whitelist.includes(origin)) {
    responseHeaders['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = origin;
    responseHeaders['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = 'true';
  } else {
    // If Origin is not allowed, deny the request
    return {
      statusCode: 403,
      headers: responseHeaders,
      body: JSON.stringify({ message: 'Origin not allowed' }),
    };
  }

  // Handle Preflight Request
  if (event.httpMethod === 'OPTIONS') {
    responseHeaders['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
    responseHeaders['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Content-Type, Authorization';
    responseHeaders['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = '3600'; // Cache for 1 hour

    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      headers: responseHeaders,
      body: '',
    };
  }

  // Handle Actual Request
  // Your business logic here

  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: responseHeaders,
    body: JSON.stringify({ message: 'Success' }),
  };
};

